# How can I detect when the Lua scripts access a global variable?

Tags: lua

I started to work with a `C++/Lua` codebase that is somewhat a mess, and when I dump the contents of `_G` in the middle of the application execution, there are hundreds of variables that I am sure were only initialized somewhere, but are not used anywhere else in the code anymore. To clean this up, I would like to setup a mechanism that will log whenever `Lua` accesses a global variable.

This was my idea of how to achieve this – I wanted to setup a proxy `_G` that would only pass all read and write accesses via `__index` and `__newindex` along to its own copy of the original `_G`. However this simple script doesn't work and only outputs:

`C:\Programs\lua-5.1.5_Win32_bin\lua5.1: error in error handling`

```
GProx = 
{
    vars = _G
}

setmetatable(GProx, {

    __index = function (t, name) 

        print("Read> " .. name)
        return t.vars[name]

    end,

    __newindex = function (t, name, val)

        print("Write> " .. name .. ' = ' .. val)
        t.vars[name] = val

    end

})

setfenv(0, GProx)

a = 1 --> Expected to print 'Write> a'
print(a) --> Expected to print 'Read> print', 'Read> a', and '1'
```

Is this a good approach or is there a better way to do this?
If this is a valid line of thought, then what is the problem with my snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this snippet instead, it will work with reads and writes:

```
do
    -- Use local variables
    local old_G, new_G = _G, {}

    -- Copy values if you want to silence logging
    -- about already set fields (eg. predeclared globals).
    -- for k, v in pairs(old_G) do new_G[k] = v end

    setmetatable(new_G, {
        __index = function (t, key)
            print("Read> " .. tostring(key))
            return old_G[key]
        end,

        __newindex = function (t, key, val)
            print("Write> " .. tostring(key) .. ' = ' .. tostring(val))
            old_G[key] = val
        end,
    })

    -- Set it at level 1 (top-level function)
    setfenv(1, new_G)
end
```

---

Here's a rundown of the changes:

- A block is used to have a local reference to the old `_G`. In your proposed implementation, if a global variable named `vars` is set, it will override `GProx.vars` and break the proxy.
- `key` and `val` should go through `tostring` before printing, since most values (ie. tables) aren't implicitly converted to strings.
- Setting the environment at level `1` is usually enough and will not mess with Lua's internal workings.

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as I needed. The important part was to set the new environment on level `1` instead of `0` -- even my original snippet starts to work as expected when I change that.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a metatable directly on the `_G` table, as explained in [PIL section 14.2](http://www.lua.org/pil/14.2.html), so you are really close. There are also a couple of existing Lua modules on the web that do this (perhaps penlight contains one).

Comment: The problem with setting the metatable directly on the _G is that the __index metamethod gets invoked only when the requested key is not present in the indexed table itself. There are many variables in my codebase which are initialised in the C++ code, but then only read in the Lua code -- which I will not be able to catch this way.